# Can make the mouse wheel scroll this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was making a slideshow, but I cant scroll through images with the mouse wheel. I tried to make it scrollable with the mouse wheel, but I always end up messing all the animation and the slides, can anyone help me with this?

```js
(function($) {
  // Variables
  var sectionFrom,
    $slide = $('.slide'),
    $slideActive = $('.slide.active'),
    $navLink = $('.nav a'),
    $navLi = $('.nav li'),
    $body = $('body');

  // Init function
  function init() {
    // Set active slide visible
    TweenLite.set($slideActive, {
      x: '0%'
    });

    // Fade slides in
    TweenLite.set($body, {
      className: '-=loading'
    });
  }
  init();

  // Navigation click
  $navLink.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      e.returnValue = false;
    }

    // prevent animation when animating
    if (!$body.hasClass('is-animating')) {
      var sectionFrom = $('.slide.active'),
        sectionToID = $(e.target).attr('href'),
        sectionTo = $('div' + sectionToID);

      if (sectionFrom.attr('id') !== sectionTo.attr('id')) {
        scrollToSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo);
      }
    }
  });

  function scrollToSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo) {

    var heading = sectionTo.find('h1'),
      subheading = sectionTo.find('p'),
      bcg = sectionTo.find('.bcg'),
      bcgFrom = sectionFrom.find('.bcg'),
      tlDown = new TimelineLite({
        onComplete: setActiveSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo)
      }),
      tlUp = new TimelineLite();

    if (sectionFrom.index() < sectionTo.index()) {
      //console.log('going down');
      tlDown
        .set($body, {
          className: '+=is-animating'
        })
        .to(sectionFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '-=100%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .to(sectionTo, 1.2, {
          x: '0%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '0')
        .to(bcgFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(bcg, 1.2, {
          x: '-30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(heading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=1')
        .from(subheading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=0.6')
        .set($body, {
          className: '-=is-animating'
        });

    } else {
      //console.log('going up');
      tlUp
        .set($body, {
          className: '+=is-animating'
        })
        .set(sectionTo, {
          x: '-100%'
        })
        .to(sectionFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '100%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .to(sectionTo, 1.2, {
          x: '0%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '0')
        .to(bcgFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '-30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(bcg, 1.2, {
          x: '30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(heading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=1')
        .from(subheading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=0.6')
        .set($body, {
          className: '-=is-animating'
        });
    }
  }

  function setActiveSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo) {
    // Add active class to the current slide
    sectionFrom.removeClass('active');
    sectionTo.addClass('active');

    // Add a body class highlighting the current slide
    $body.removeAttr('class').addClass($(sectionTo).attr('id') + '-active');

    // Highlight current slide in the navigation
    var currentSlideIndex = parseInt($(sectionTo).attr('id').slice(-2)) - 1;
    $navLi.removeAttr('class');
    $navLi.eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #2e2e30;
  color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.slidesContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slideContent h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.slideContent p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0;
}

/* =Project Slides */
.slide {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, visibility 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.loading {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.bcg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide01 .bcg {
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/91/f9/8091f9dceb2ea55fa7b57bb7295e1824--hd-iphone--wallpapers-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg');
}

.slide02 .bcg {
  background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/880665-road-wallpapers.jpg);
}

.slide03 .bcg {
  background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/91/f9/8091f9dceb2ea55fa7b57bb7295e1824--hd-iphone--wallpapers-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg');
}

.slide04 .bcg {
  background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/880665-road-wallpapers.jpg);
}

.slide04 .slideContent h1 {
  color: #222;
}

.slide04 .slideContent p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

/* =Navigation */
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.nav li:last-child a {
  border-width: 1px
}

.nav li.active a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidesContainer">

  <div id="slide01" class="slide slide01 active">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 1 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide02" class="slide slide02">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 2 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide03" class="slide slide03">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 3 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide04" class="slide slide04">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 4 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#slide01">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide02">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide03">Slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide04">Slide 4</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  When I run the snippet, it looks fine.

Comment: that you cant scroll through images, you cant use the mousewheel, i want to get that effect to

Comment: @BarbaraLaird can you help me? to Achieve that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `data-slide` attribute to each slide & same value is given as id to your `anchor` tag. Then added `mousewheel` event for `.slide` & just triggered the click event on that `anchor` which has `data-slide` attribute as id. It will change the slide to next on scroll.

```js
(function($) {

  // Variables
  var sectionFrom,
    $slide = $('.slide'),
    $slideActive = $('.slide.active'),
    $navLink = $('.nav a'),
    $navLi = $('.nav li'),
    $body = $('body');

  // Init function
  function init() {

    // Set active slide visible
    TweenLite.set($slideActive, {
      x: '0%'
    });

    // Fade slides in
    TweenLite.set($body, {
      className: '-=loading'
    });

  }
  init();

  // Navigation click
  $navLink.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      e.returnValue = false;
    }

    // prevent animation when animating
    if (!$body.hasClass('is-animating')) {

      var sectionFrom = $('.slide.active'),
        sectionToID = $(e.target).attr('href'),
        sectionTo = $('div' + sectionToID);

      if (sectionFrom.attr('id') !== sectionTo.attr('id')) {

        scrollToSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo);

      }

    }

  });

  function scrollToSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo) {

    var heading = sectionTo.find('h1'),
      subheading = sectionTo.find('p'),
      bcg = sectionTo.find('.bcg'),
      bcgFrom = sectionFrom.find('.bcg'),
      tlDown = new TimelineLite({
        onComplete: setActiveSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo)
      }),
      tlUp = new TimelineLite();

    if (sectionFrom.index() < sectionTo.index()) {

      //console.log('going down');
      tlDown
        .set($body, {
          className: '+=is-animating'
        })
        .to(sectionFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '-=100%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .to(sectionTo, 1.2, {
          x: '0%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '0')
        .to(bcgFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(bcg, 1.2, {
          x: '-30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(heading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=1')
        .from(subheading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=0.6')
        .set($body, {
          className: '-=is-animating'
        });

    } else {

      //console.log('going up');
      tlUp
        .set($body, {
          className: '+=is-animating'
        })
        .set(sectionTo, {
          x: '-100%'
        })
        .to(sectionFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '100%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .to(sectionTo, 1.2, {
          x: '0%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '0')
        .to(bcgFrom, 1.2, {
          x: '-30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(bcg, 1.2, {
          x: '30%',
          ease: Power4.easeInOut,
          clearProps: 'all'
        }, '0')
        .from(heading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=1')
        .from(subheading, 0.7, {
          autoAlpha: 0,
          x: 40,
          ease: Power4.easeInOut
        }, '-=0.6')
        .set($body, {
          className: '-=is-animating'
        });
    }

  }

  function setActiveSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo) {

    // Add active class to the current slide
    sectionFrom.removeClass('active');
    sectionTo.addClass('active');

    // Add a body class highlighting the current slide
    $body.removeAttr('class').addClass($(sectionTo).attr('id') + '-active');

    // Highlight current slide in the navigation
    var currentSlideIndex = parseInt($(sectionTo).attr('id').slice(-2)) - 1;
    $navLi.removeAttr('class');
    $navLi.eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');

  }

})(jQuery);


$('.slide').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
$("#"+$(this).attr('data-slide')).trigger('click');
    });
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #2e2e30;
  color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.slidesContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slideContent h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.slideContent p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0;
}


/* =Project Slides */

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, visibility 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.loading {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.bcg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide01 .bcg {
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/91/f9/8091f9dceb2ea55fa7b57bb7295e1824--hd-iphone--wallpapers-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg');
}

.slide02 .bcg {
  background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/880665-road-wallpapers.jpg);
}

.slide03 .bcg {
  background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/91/f9/8091f9dceb2ea55fa7b57bb7295e1824--hd-iphone--wallpapers-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg');
}

.slide04 .bcg {
  background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/880665-road-wallpapers.jpg);
}

.slide04 .slideContent h1 {
  color: #222;
}

.slide04 .slideContent p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}


/* =Navigation */

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.nav li:last-child a {
  border-width: 1px
}

.nav li.active a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidesContainer">

  <div id="slide01" data-slide="s1" class="slide slide01 active">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 1 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide02" data-slide="s2" class="slide slide02">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 2 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide03" data-slide="s3" class="slide slide03">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 3 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide04" data-slide="s0" class="slide slide04">
    <div class="bcg"></div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      <h1>Slide 4 Title</h1>
      <p>This is a short description.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a id="s0" href="#slide01">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="s1" href="#slide02">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="s2" href="#slide03">Slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="s3" href="#slide04">Slide 4</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: ohhhh meeennn i love you jjjajaj, just thank you soo much, but one thing how can we make it full control? i mean go reverse, all directions, foward and backwards? and have the control with the scroll

Comment: We can easily make forward backwards but you need to search for control with scroll. I am not sure for that